# How can I form a composite Function with Theano?

Tags: python, theano, composition

I would like to compute a composite function f(x, g(x)) with Theano. Unfortunately, when I try to code a function composition, Python complains about a TypeError. For example, consider the following simple script:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x = T.dscalar('x')

def g():
    y1 = T.sqr(x)
    return theano.function([x], y1)

def composition():
    input = g()
    yComp = x * input
    return  theano.function([x], yComp)

def f():
    y1 = T.sqr(x)
    yMult = x * y1
    return theano.function([x], yMult)
```

When writing  `funComp = composition()`  Python returns a TypeError:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'TensorVariable' and 'Function'
```

However, I can compile and calculate the function  `fun = f()` . Is there a way to successfully establish a function composition? I am grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple function actually for this case. This one works well.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x = T.dscalar('x')


def g():
    y1 = T.sqr(x)
    return y1

def composition():
    input = g()
    yComp = x * input
    return  theano.function([x], yComp)

tfunc = composition()
print tfunc(4)
```

Comment: @maliobro: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, when I run the script and with f = composition() at the end and then try to calculate f(1.1) (for example) Python says  TypeError: 'TensorVariable' object is not callable. Do you have an idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: @fabian I'm sorry for late reply, I was confused with your f() function, but these functions was a working composition function. I have edit my code, try it.